# Why KeyError: 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror

I'm attempting to solve Project Euler 21 but I'm getting KeyError: 0 which normally occurs when you refer to a dictionary key that doesn't exist. However, I thought I had solved that problem with the < 10000 condition. The error refers to the first 'if' statement in the main() function.

```
sumsdivs = {}
for i in range(1, 10000):
    tmpls = []
    for j in range(1, i):
        if i % j == 0:
            tmpls.append(j)
    sumsdivs[i] = sum(tmpls)

amls = []
def main():
    for i in range(1, 10000):
        if sumsdivs[i] < 10000 and sumsdivs[i] == sumsdivs[sumsdivs[i]]:
            if sumsdivs[i] not in amls:
                amls.append(sumsdivs[i])
            if sumsdivs[sumsdivs[i]] not in amls:
                amls.append(sumsdivs[sumsdivs[i]])
    return sum(amls)

print(main())
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `sumsdivs[sumsdivs[i]]` could throw the exception if `sumdivs[i]` is 0.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That can't be true. For there to be a `0` in `sumsdivs`, `tmpls` must be an empty list, but it always includes `1` as every `range(1, n)` list includes `1` and `n % 1 == 0`

Comment: @Haidro: `sumsdivs[1]` is `0`.

Comment: Good point, am checking now...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, I see. `range(1, 1)` is `[]`, not `[1]`

Comment: Basic debugging would have found this error. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 7):

You insert `0` for `i = 1` here:

```
sumsdivs = {}
for i in range(1, 10000):
    tmpls = []
    for j in range(1, i):
        if i % j == 0:
            tmpls.append(j)
    sumsdivs[i] = sum(tmpls)
```

The inner loop never runs (`range(1, 1)` is empty), and `sum([])` is 0.

Demo:

```
>>> sumsdivs = {}
>>> for i in range(1, 2):
...     tmpls = []
...     for j in range(1, i):
...         if i % j == 0:
...             tmpls.append(j)
...     sumsdivs[i] = sum(tmpls)
... 
>>> sumsdivs
{1: 0}
>>> sum([])
0
```

So `sumsdivs[1]` is 0, and `sumsdivs[sumsdivs[0]]` throws a `KeyError`:

```
>>> sumsdivs[sumsdivs[1]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 0
```